# Mapbox Annotation

Tags: ios, mapbox

I want to create multiple annotations with different images. To create the annotations, in viewDidLoad:

```
for (int i=0; i<[annotationsArray count]; i++) {
    RMAnnotation *annotation = [[RMAnnotation alloc]
                                initWithMapView:mapView
                                coordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[latitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue], [[longitudeArray objectAtIndex:i] doubleValue])
                                andTitle:[nameArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

}
```

In the method below, it gives every annotation the same image:

```
- (RMMapLayer *)mapView:(RMMapView *)mapView layerForAnnotation:(RMAnnotation *)annotation
{
    if (annotation.isUserLocationAnnotation) {
        return nil;
    }
    RMMarker *marker = [[RMMarker alloc] initWithUIImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CoffeeShopsIcon.png"]];

    marker.canShowCallout = YES;

    marker.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CoffeeShopsIcon.png"]];

    marker.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    return marker;
}
```

I have an array that holds the image names. How can I achieve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `-[RMAnnotation userInfo]` API.

```
/** Storage for arbitrary data. */
@property (nonatomic, strong) id userInfo;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a property on your RMAnnotation that denotes which image to use and then create your marker based on this property for each annotation.